# Nuxt, Strapi can't get media url

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, strapi

Could you guys please check my code and help me out.
I've uploaded some media to strapi and assigned them to each drink. Now I want to access that data with axios, I can get id, description, title etc. but I can not get URL from media.
Anyone could help please. Thanks!

NUXT:

```js
<v-img
  :src="'url(${http://localhost:1337}/drink.media.url)'"     
></v-img>
 


<script>
  async created() {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get("http://localhost:1337/drinks");
      this.drinks = response.data;
    } catch (error) {
      this.error = error;
    }
    console.log(this.drinks)
  },
  
};
</script>
```

JSON FROM POSTMAN

```js
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "Coca-Cola",
        "description": null,
        "price": 1,
        "published_at": "2021-10-16T19:02:52.099Z",
        "created_at": "2021-10-16T19:01:26.228Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-10-16T19:02:52.124Z",
        "unit": 250,
        "media": [
                "hash": "coca_cola_original_282x130_8baa6d1d20",
                "ext": ".webp",
                "mime": "image/webp",
                "size": 37.01,
                "url": "/uploads/coca_cola_original_282x130_8baa6d1d20.webp",
                "previewUrl": null,
                "provider": "local",
                "provider_metadata": null,
                "created_at": "2021-10-16T18:56:02.187Z",
                "updated_at": "2021-10-16T18:56:02.206Z"
            }
        ]
    },
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you upload your images in strapi, but below I describe my method for uploading images of book covers in my strapi local-host and the way I access the image in my nuxt app. Maybe it is helpful for you to use it in your app.

First I made a new media field in my strapi "content-types builder" section and named it "bookCover". after that I upload my image in database for each book.

Second I used [**fetch()**](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/data-fetching/) instead of **created** hook in my Nuxt app. below is the code of my Nuxt page script:

```js
data() {
  return {
    books: [],
  }
},

async fetch() {
  this.books = await this.$axios.$get('http://localhost:1337/books');
}
```

Finally according to [Nuxt documentation](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/data-fetching/#accessing-the-fetch-state) I used this code in my **template** part of my page:

```html
<div>
  <p v-if="$fetchState.pending">Fetching mountains...</p>
  <p v-else-if="$fetchState.error">An error occurred :(</p>
  <div v-else>
<!-- you must enter your index of drinks, for example here I access the first book image -->
    <v-img max-width="250" :src="`http://localhost:1337${this.books[0].bookCover.url}`"></v-img>
  </div>
</div>
```

I think if you use this method and use "fetch" hook and also modify the way you call `src` attribute in `"v-img"`, you can access your image. Also notice that my variable names are different from your names and you must change them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've made a mistake and created a media with pamameter "Multiple Media" instead of "Single media". With your code and Single media type it finally works thanks!